# jquery function runs only once

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have this function below.  Works great and is from http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/  (by far the best and easiet I have found if anyone else is after a carousel)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#foo1').carouFredSel({
     auto: {
     pauseOnHover: 'resume',
     progress: '#timer1'
     }
    });
  });
</script>
```

anyway I the carousel loops through a selection of images.  Now I have a separate function that reloads the div through an ajax call below.  It populates the div with a new set of images based on the users selection of folder.

```
<script>
  function getImages(id)
  {
     $.ajax({

 type: "GET",
 url: 'getImage.php',
 data: "id=" + id, 
 success: function(data) {

      $('#scrolimg').html(data);
    }

   });

  }
</script>
```

This too works fine.  The problem is when you have clicked a new folder and it reloads refreshes the div the carousel stops completely.  Is there anyway based on the success of the ajax call to re fire the jquery function to get the carousel going again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the callback function of the AJAX you call, you have to re-apply:

```
success: function(data) {  
        $('#foo1').carouFredSel({
            auto: {
                pauseOnHover: 'resume',
                progress: '#timer1'

            }
        });
...
}
```

If you are using a `.html()` function or similar to re-write the `foo` element, you are erasing any event associated to it too, so you have to call it again.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this into your callback:

```
$('#foo1').carouFredSel({
    auto: {
        pauseOnHover: 'resume',
        progress: '#timer1'

    }
});
```

It should work. Respect!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing in your example foo1 == scrolimg, do this:

```
<script>
  function getImages(id)
  {
     $.ajax({

 type: "GET",
 url: 'getImage.php',
 data: "id=" + id, 
 success: function(data) {

      $('#scrolimg')
         .carouFredSel('destroy')
         .html(data)
         .carouFredSel({
            auto: {
            pauseOnHover: 'resume',
            progress: '#timer1'
           }
         });
      }

   });

  }
</script>
```